# Deconstructing nested tuples of tuples recursively into a flat list of connections

Tags: python, networkx

I thought I was clever in storing the results of a recursive clustering algorithm as a nest of nested tuples. The data stores all relationsips between IDs like this:

```
((((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))), ((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))),
((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L))))))), (((((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L))))), (((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), 
 (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)))))), ((((((11162L, 9208L), (6992L, 5965L)), ((9208L, 11317L), (10834L, 11318L))), (((12705L, 12769L), (3825L, 7779L)), ((12334L, 12414L), (12769L, 7059L)))), ((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L))))), (((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L)))))))), ((((((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L)))), ((((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L)), ((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))), (((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))))), (((((9225L, 9777L), (6895L, 8167L)), ((10686L, 5395L), (12384L, 6816L))), (((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L)))), ((((9175L, 7918L), (6780L, 8004L)), ((6780L, 8004L), (10831L, 9175L))), (((6908L, 11020L), (10419L, 10235L)), ((11200L, 9756L), (11021L, 11462L)))))), 
((((((10031L, 8445L), (6165L, 8329L)), ((8445L, 12689L), (10031L, 8445L))), (((5350L, 6189L), (7374L, 5782L)), ((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)))), ((((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L))), (((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)), ((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L))))), (((((7613L, 11184L), (11184L, 5673L)), ((8929L, 5318L), (8378L, 8929L))), (((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L)), ((8378L, 8929L), (5363L, 5910L)))), ((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L))))))), (((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))), 
((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))), 
 ((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L))))))))
```

I am now trying to convert this object into a list of edges to visualize with networkx. So each pair of IDs is easy to connect -- such as 10500 and 11781. But I also need to connect each nest to its parent, so (10500 and 11781) would each need an edge connection to a upper node that branches to that pair and to (3825, 7779). Am I going about this all wrong?

The best template I found was for flattening any data structure. It at least has some logic about walking through the object that I understand:

```
def flatten(l, ltypes=(list, tuple)):
""" stolen from http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html
AKA  Mike C. Fletcher's BasicTypes library"""
ltype = type(l)
l = list(l)
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    while isinstance(l[i], ltypes):
        if not l[i]:
            l.pop(i)
            i -= 1
            break
        else:
            l[i:i + 1] = l[i]
    i += 1
return ltype(l)
```

to clarify, each upper level has an ID made up of the previous levels. Here are 6 levels for example:

```
((((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L)))), ((((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L)), ((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))), (((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))))), (((((9225L, 9777L), (6895L, 8167L)), ((10686L, 5395L), (12384L, 6816L))), (((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L)))), ((((9175L, 7918L), (6780L, 8004L)), ((6780L, 8004L), (10831L, 9175L))), (((6908L, 11020L), (10419L, 10235L)), ((11200L, 9756L), (11021L, 11462L))))))

(((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L)))), ((((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L)), ((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))), (((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L)))))

((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L))))

(((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L)))

((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))

(9386L, 8168L)

9386L
```

Generated with this little recursive walker:

```
def pluck(data_in,out):
    if not isinstance(data_in[0], tuple):
        return out
    print data_in[0]
    out.append(data_in[0])
    pluck(data_in[0],out)
```

Does that clear it up? I don't want a flat list - I was a list of connected members like a tree fractal. Suggestions?

**UPDATE**
Some nice person posted a useful function that kinda worked- but it is missing from SO now, so I reposting. The good part is that it pushes all tuples into one list of tuples. The bad part is that networkx still doesn't connect all the members in the final map:

```
def flatten(t, out):
    if isinstance(t[0], tuple):
        for p in t:
            flatten(p, out)
    else:
        out.append(t)
    return out

out = []
out = flatten(data,out)
```

Comment: This upper node does not have an ID?

Comment: You might want to use `namedtuple` next time: `Edge = namedtuple("Edge", ["from", "to"])`.

Comment: So the first item in each tuple is the parent ID and the remainder are children IDs?

Comment: the lowest level of the tuples are pairs, then pairs are combined into "pairs of pairs" then "pairs of pairs of pairs"... and so on. So the parentheses of the tuples define the level of recursion depth.

Comment: Yes - although I'm not at all familiar with binary trees. Is the a module that handles this stuff within python easier?

Comment: So it looks like traversing each member of the tree and connecting adjacent members is not a trivial task - whole wiki page on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
tree = (((((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))), ((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))),((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L))))))), (((((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L))))), (((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))),  (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)))))), ((((((11162L, 9208L), (6992L, 5965L)), ((9208L, 11317L), (10834L, 11318L))), (((12705L, 12769L), (3825L, 7779L)), ((12334L, 12414L), (12769L, 7059L)))), ((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L))))), (((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L)))))))), ((((((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L)))), ((((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L)), ((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))), (((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))))), (((((9225L, 9777L), (6895L, 8167L)), ((10686L, 5395L), (12384L, 6816L))), (((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L)))), ((((9175L, 7918L), (6780L, 8004L)), ((6780L, 8004L), (10831L, 9175L))), (((6908L, 11020L), (10419L, 10235L)), ((11200L, 9756L), (11021L, 11462L)))))), ((((((10031L, 8445L), (6165L, 8329L)), ((8445L, 12689L), (10031L, 8445L))), (((5350L, 6189L), (7374L, 5782L)), ((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)))), ((((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L))), (((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)), ((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L))))), (((((7613L, 11184L), (11184L, 5673L)), ((8929L, 5318L), (8378L, 8929L))), (((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L)), ((8378L, 8929L), (5363L, 5910L)))), ((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L))))))), (((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))), ((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))),  ((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L)))))))))


graph = nx.Graph()

def create_graph(id,tree,graph):
    if id!=0:
        parent = (id-1)/2
        graph.add_edge(parent,id)
    if isinstance(tree[0],tuple) and isinstance(tree[1],tuple):
        create_graph(id*2+1,tree[0],graph)
        create_graph(id*2+2,tree[1],graph)
    else:
        graph.add_edge(id,tree[0])
        graph.add_edge(id,tree[1])
        graph.add_edge(tree[0],tree[1])

create_graph(0,tree,graph)
```

Comment: That seems to have done something... interesting.. I can't quite say it "worked" yet - because the resulting network map is all chaotic looking, though the tuple version was a full and perfect binary tree.

Comment: Here's simplified version without global variables. Yes the graph representation is a bit chaotic but some of the elements in the list are appearing multiple times i.e. 8953L is listed three times.

Comment: So another observation - because your create_graph function calls itself recursively and assigns arbitrary node numbers, it makes it quite difficult to assign text labels to these nodes based on the ID#s that were stored - is there a tweak to save the ID#s as node numbers in the graph?

Comment: At least with some of the labels matching up to nodes (I think) -- the  resulting map seems to make sense, so I think your trick worked. Now just to make sure the NODE IDs are connected to the right labels...

Comment: And thanks for killing the global variables - I really don't like use globals.

Comment: Those nodes that get arbitrary number do not have an label in the tree list since they are created dynamically. Only tree leaves are labeled.

Comment: and when I call this the first time, will it look like this: 

    graph = nx.DiGraph(data=None)
    graph = create_graph(graph,matched.keys(),graph)

I added a "return graph" to the end of your function, will that break it?

Comment: I have made an update so labels of the dynamically created nodes are no longer arbitrary. What do you mean when you said call this the first time? Return is not needed since function works on a graph that you have created outside of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19659/discussion-between-marc-maxson-and-bula)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar approach to @Bula but that uses tuples as "internal nodes" in the tree.  You could relabel those as you like.  I didn't draw any of the labels so you won't seem them here anyway.

```
import networkx as nx
import uuid

tree = ((((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))), ((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))),
((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L))))))), (((((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L))))), (((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))),
 (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)))))), ((((((11162L, 9208L), (6992L, 5965L)), ((9208L, 11317L), (10834L, 11318L))), (((12705L, 12769L), (3825L, 7779L)), ((12334L, 12414L), (12769L, 7059L)))), ((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L))))), (((((11318L, 10181L), (12334L, 12414L)), ((12292L, 11221L), (11221L, 9262L))), (((12721L, 961L), (11245L, 5132L)), ((12414L, 11245L), (12721L, 961L)))), ((((11248L, 12034L), (9972L, 11248L)), ((10948L, 12013L), (10823L, 5602L))), (((10839L, 10948L), (6673L, 10839L)), ((10729L, 9687L), (1300L, 12274L)))))))), ((((((((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))), (((8225L, 8804L), (8804L, 6369L)), ((8289L, 8953L), (8225L, 8804L)))), ((((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L)), ((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L))), (((9386L, 8168L), (8876L, 7622L)), ((6311L, 5727L), (7174L, 3611L))))), (((((9225L, 9777L), (6895L, 8167L)), ((10686L, 5395L), (12384L, 6816L))), (((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L)))), ((((9175L, 7918L), (6780L, 8004L)), ((6780L, 8004L), (10831L, 9175L))), (((6908L, 11020L), (10419L, 10235L)), ((11200L, 9756L), (11021L, 11462L)))))),
((((((10031L, 8445L), (6165L, 8329L)), ((8445L, 12689L), (10031L, 8445L))), (((5350L, 6189L), (7374L, 5782L)), ((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)))), ((((5395L, 10211L), (10686L, 5395L)), ((10891L, 10127L), (6816L, 5622L))), (((8355L, 7054L), (6536L, 9380L)), ((9380L, 7698L), (6450L, 8876L))))), (((((7613L, 11184L), (11184L, 5673L)), ((8929L, 5318L), (8378L, 8929L))), (((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L)), ((8378L, 8929L), (5363L, 5910L)))), ((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L))))))), (((((((8953L, 3409L), (8334L, 7375L)), ((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L))), (((7375L, 7220L), (8420L, 8556L)), ((8420L, 8556L), (8556L, 10089L)))), ((((11021L, 11462L), (6778L, 6854L)), ((10691L, 6652L), (11061L, 11230L))), (((6652L, 5660L), (10691L, 6652L)), ((8390L, 6032L), (10984L, 11061L))))), (((((7406L, 11878L), (8398L, 7493L)), ((10419L, 10235L), (6377L, 6439L))), (((8367L, 6199L), (7263L, 7406L)), ((6199L, 7900L), (8367L, 6199L)))),
((((8667L, 9142L), (6491L, 7771L)), ((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L))), (((10391L, 8808L), (8667L, 9142L)), ((5882L, 9575L), (7008L, 6048L)))))), ((((((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)), ((11294L, 9923L), (8390L, 6032L))), (((10656L, 11087L), (11087L, 9623L)), ((11087L, 9623L), (9013L, 9969L)))), ((((6590L, 10794L), (12483L, 6590L)), ((10794L, 8997L), (6590L, 10794L))), (((12386L, 12544L), (8196L, 11139L)), ((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L))))), (((((11266L, 11269L), (10751L, 12192L)), ((6905L, 8811L), (11180L, 9732L))), (((12338L, 12701L), (12474L, 12569L)), ((9948L, 10073L), (8577L, 10217L)))),
 ((((8997L, 11091L), (11091L, 11210L)), ((10751L, 12192L), (12543L, 12143L))), (((961L, 12029L), (9262L, 11900L)), ((3825L, 7779L), (10500L, 11781L))))))))

def add_edges(graph, tree):
    try:
        left,right = tree
    except TypeError:
        return
    graph.add_edge(tree,left)
    graph.add_edge(tree,right)
    add_edges(graph,left)
    add_edges(graph,right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    graph = nx.Graph()
    add_edges(graph,tree)
    nx.draw(graph,node_size=10,with_labels=False)
# nicer layout with graphviz is you have it
#    nx.draw_graphviz(graph,node_size=10,with_labels=False)
    plt.show()
```